# Using AND statement in a pg_query() issue

Tags: php, postgresql

Currently experiencing a weird difficulty with a PostgresSQL query I made to retrieve user credentials from a database.
Please disregard the security-wise approach; for testing purposes only.

Using the following query:

```
$result = pg_query($dbconnection,"SELECT \"username\" AND \"password\" FROM \"user\" WHERE      \"username\"='$_USER' AND \"password\"='$encryptedPassword'");
```

This gives the following error

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type character varying LINE 1: SELECT "username" AND "password" FROM "user" WHERE "username... ^

I find this very strange as I've used AND queries after a FROM statement before...
Does this have to do with improper notation?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `AND` from the `SELECT` part

```
SELECT username, password
FROM user 
WHERE username = '$_USER' 
AND password ='$encryptedPassword'
```

Comment: Thanks! Working now. Guess I got caught offguard when switching from mySQL earlier today.

Comment: The syntax is the same in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

ummm... thats not sql, use a comma not and

```
$result = pg_query($dbconnection,"SELECT \"username\",\"password\" FROM \"user\" WHERE      \"username\"='$_USER' AND \"password\"='$encryptedPassword'");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did mix up the notation!

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = pg_query($dbconnection,"SELECT 'username', 'password' FROM user WHERE username='".$_USER."' AND password='".$encryptedPassword."'");
```

Comment: Hm, without quotes I'm getting an error saying that username is not an column. With quotes, I do not, though.

Comment: Query failed: ERROR: column "username" does not exist